# Pure CSS Add Link :before content

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Is it possible to make a clickable link with pure css, specifically with pseudo elements? Maybe something like this:

```
body:before{
  content: url(/images/makeALinkOutOfMe.png);
  link: '/imYourLink';
}
```

Or

```
body:before{
  content: 'make a link out of me';
  link: '/imYourLink';
}
```

I know it is not possible to write `HTML` in the `content` declaration. But is there some way to get around this?

I want to use pure css if the user decides to turn off JavaScript.

Comment: No, it's not possible with pure CSS.

Comment: unfortunately i think your best option is going to be to have 'fallback' elements that are removed/hidden when JS _is_ available..

Comment: that's too bad. The way I'm working on this I won't be able to have fall back HTML. Maybe I'll just make a message that says turn on JavaScript! It would be nice if I didn't have to say that though.

Comment: @Jon49 That's definitely acceptable. Everything requires JS these days. Just through in a `<noscript>` element.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but you can show the url of links in printed webpages.

```
@media print {
  a[href]:after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ") ";
  }
}
```

Apart from that I dont think its possible, also if the user turns off JavaScript the HTML  tag will still work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, not really what I am looking for. I was looking for a way to add a link since I won't have access to the HTML content if JavaScript isn't enabled.